# Bitbucket 2.0 API get all commits merged to master

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to create a utility tool for which I need to get the list of all commits that have been merged to master from the feature branch on Bitbucket. As you can see in the picture, the commit that has "M" label after the commit id is the one that I need. However, when I use the endpoint - https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user-name/repo-name/commits/master - it returns me a list of all the commits including the ones that do not have the label 'M'.

Is there any way I can get a list of only the commits that have been merged to master?

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7uZr.png)

Answer (score 0):

to get only the merge commits the parameter "merger is used".
 https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/user-name/repo-name/commits/master/merge=only